# Image proxy caching problems - wrong headers?

Tags: php, http, caching

I have a proxy script on my website, which downscales images (also keeps them in local cache folder) and sends them to user, together with Etag, Caching headers etc.

However, when you visit the page, you can clearly see the images slowly loading, even when you close the tab and go there again - clearly they should be in cache (or maybe my connection sucks, but I saw them reloading even on 64 MB/s connection)

You can see the images here, the header photos: http://www.ondrovo.com/

I suspect I send the wrong headers somehow, I'm not really sure with those.

Here's my image delivery function (shortened a bit):

```
/** Send file to user */
public static function send($file)
{
    // ETAG
    $last_modified_time = filemtime($file);
    $etag = md5_file($file);

    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified_time)." GMT");
    header("Etag: $etag");
    header('Expires: pageload + 168 hours');
    header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, must-revalidate');

    // exit if not modified
    if (@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == $last_modified_time ||
        @trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) == $etag) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
        exit;
    }

    $mimetype = self::getMime($path);
    if(in_array($mimetype, ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/pjpeg'])) {
        // it's an image
        if(isset($_GET['w']) || isset($_GET['h'])) {
            // resize, save to cache folder
            // $tmp_fname holds the path to the resized image
            $file = $tmp_fname;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    readfile($file);
    flush();
    exit;
}
```

Also, here's a header dump, if it helps

**Request**

```
GET /about/header.jpg?h=92&w=92 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ondrovo.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.ondrovo.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: cs,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: PHPSESSID=64e177be06a1b7bb665dd756151d014f
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Nov 2014 18:31:57 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: pageload + 168 hours
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 14:39:09 GMT
ETag: b38a22993d1fb1ee17905067340596e4
Content-Length: 2268
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Via: 1.1 vhost.phx6.nearlyfreespeech.net:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE7)
```

Would anyone please be so kind to review my headers if they are OK?

Also, maybe is it a problem that the images get their size via GET parameters?

Comment: confirm that strtotime() is actually converting your header timestamp properly. Don't ever depend on it doing the 'right thing'. It's good, but it's not infallible, and definitely not omniscient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your header `Expires: pageload + 168 hours` doesn't conform to the right syntax. It shall be a timestamp.

> 5.3. Expires
>
> The "Expires" header field gives the date/time after which the
> response is considered stale.  See Section 4.2 for further discussion
> of the freshness model.
>
> The presence of an Expires field does not imply that the original
> resource will change or cease to exist at, before, or after that
> time.
>
> The Expires value is an HTTP-date timestamp, as defined in Section
> 7.1.1.1 of [RFC7231].
>
> ```
>  Expires = HTTP-date
> ```
>
> For example
>
> ```
>  Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
> ```
>
> A cache recipient MUST interpret invalid date formats, especially
> the    value "0", as representing a time in the past (i.e., "already
> expired").

[rfc 7234, section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3)

However, the `Cache-Control` header should be overriding it for the client.

What client where you using for the trace? It looks like it was explicitely requested to reload the whole page, both from the presence of

> Pragma: no-cache
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> (asking the squid server not to serve cached content)

And the lack of headers that would a suggest the client already has the resource cached (If-None-Match, If-Modified-Since).

Note that if visiting the site in private/incognito mode, depending on the implementation of the feature, the browser may not be caching **any** resource.

Comment: Looks like correcting the expires tag helped quite a lot, actually. Also, I've discovered that my image resizing script didn't use png compression, so that might've contributed even to load times from local cache. Easily made 1MB from 64kB image.